# Call Java class in SoapUI Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I am trying to call java class from Groovy script in SoapUI

My Java Class

```
public class LogTest {
    public void sayHello (){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }   
}
```

Groovy script

```
import LogTest;

new LogTest().sayHello()
```

I places the LogTest.class in `...SmartBear\SoapUI-4.6.1\bin\ext` path and restart SoapUI

But still I am getting following error in SoapUI

```
:ERROR:org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script5.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class LogTest
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import LogTest;
   ^
org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class LogTest
 @ line 1, column 1.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1240)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:148)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$8.call(CompilationUnit.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:839)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:544)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:493)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:306)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:287)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:731)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:743)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:770)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:761)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:149)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:239)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:48)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:148)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:43)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What could be the possible root cause

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Were you able to resolve this issue? If not I ran into the same scenario, and here is how I fixed it.

I had a jar file (HelloWorldTest.jar) with the following information:

```
package helloworldtest;

public class HWT {

    public static String Testing() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

Notice that my file name and package name are different. Make sure when importing into Groovy you use the package name.

I used:

```
import helloworldtest.HWT;

log.info HWT.Testing();
```

Result would be:

```
Thu Mar 06 16:26:01 PST 2014:INFO:Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a jar file containing your code (LogTest)
2. Put that jar file in the /bin/ext directory.

This will allow you to call your code from a Groovy script.

Comment: I created SoapJava.jar file using LogTest.class and placed in the ext folder. Still I am getting an error `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script6.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class SoapJava @ line 1, column 1. import SoapJava ^ `

Comment: did you re-start SOAP-UI?  That might be necessary.

Comment: Yes I did before run the test. Is anything wrong with the script, how I called?